# How do I use a PEM key that has key and cert in the same file in nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I got a file (and a matching passphrase) from a client that is supposed to replace my letsencrypt setup.
It looks like this:

`[domain.pem]`

```
subject=CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
issuer=CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

subject=CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1M, OU="(c) 2014 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
issuer=CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

subject=CN=domain, SERIALNUMBER=11 111 111 111, OID.2.5.4.15=Private Organization, O=Corp, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US, L=CITY, S=STATE, C=US
issuer=CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1M, OU="(c) 2014 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: SOME-LETTERS

-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

My nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    # [...]

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/path/to/domain.pem; # assuming I need the same file here?
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/path/to/domain.pem;

    ssl_session_timeout  1d;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets  off;

    ssl_protocols              TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    ssl_dhparam                /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';

    # OCSP Stapling ---
    # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
    ssl_stapling         on;
    ssl_stapling_verify  on;

    # [...]
}
```

Now when I try to run it in test mode I get:

```
$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/path/to/domain.pem") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

### What I tried so far

I tried creating a plain key from the file via:

```
openssl rsa -in domain.pem -out domain-plain.key
```

And include that but the hash wouldn't match anymore now:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in domain.pem | openssl md5
206508ae007125edb1b6a26db39213c2

$ openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in domain-plain.key | openssl md5
050b90ff7080b1b1b550ea401b15aaee
```

### Questions

Maybe there is a way to extract the key and the cert separately?

Is there another way to just use the file directly in my nginx config with a password file via `ssl_password_file` maybe? I just can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: The server or **leaf cert** (the block beginning with `subject=CN=domain` assuming that's actually the correct domain and you redacted it, and ending with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`) **must be FIRST** in the file, and the intermediate/CA certs AFTER. [See the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate) (they call it 'primary')

Comment: Nice catch! Thank you. If I change the order I'm sure the passcode won't work anymore via `openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in domain.pem`. (And yes I redacted most of the data)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 do you want to make this an answer cause this fixed my issue and I like to give you imaginary internet points for helping :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just to complete this question with an answer*

As @dave_thompson_085 pointed out the order of the keys is important.
The primary key must be first followed by the CA key.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate

Simply rearranging the keys did the job so I have:

```
subject=CN=domain, SERIALNUMBER=11 111 111 111, OID.2.5.4.15=Private Organization, O=Corp, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US, L=CITY, S=STATE, C=US
issuer=CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1M, OU="(c) 2014 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

subject=CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1M, OU="(c) 2014 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
issuer=CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

subject=CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
issuer=CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only", OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: SOME-LETTERS

-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Also good to note that all other text not inside the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` is ignored by OpenSSL as pointed out by @Mircea Vutcovici.

Answer (score 2):

I would put the private key in a separate file. And make sure the permissions are very restrictive.

The host certificate followed by all intermediate ones in another file. This file you can give more lax permissions: you can give read access for all users.

The certificate "subject=CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority" is not needed.

`ssl_certificate` will point to the certificates file. `ssl_certificate_key` should point to the key file.

The important parts are those starting and ending with dashes, including those dashes. Any other text is just comments. Make sure that the comments are matching the ASCII armored certificates and the key. `openssl s_client -text -in file_with_only_one_cert.txt`

Comment: Changing the order fixed my issues as @dave_thompson_085 suggested but thank you for more infos. I'd love to clean this mess up

Comment: It's not that bad. But certificates are a bit complex.